# Can't connect to mongo db via js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I wrote a code for integrating all types of social networking log ins with nodejs. Here is my **server.js**

```
// get all the tools we need
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');

var morgan       = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var session      = require('express-session');

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');

// configuration ===============================================================
mongoose.connect(configDB); // connect to our database

// require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

// set up our express application
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser()); // get information from html forms

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating

// required for passport
app.use(session({ secret: '234545671290eftg5678qwer235623' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

// routes ======================================================================
//require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport

// launch ======================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);
```

**config/database.js**

```
module.exports = {

    'url' : 'mongodb://localhost27017:' // looks like mongodb://<user>:<pass>@mongo.onmodulus.net:27017/Mikha4ot

};
```

When I run `node server`, I get the following error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: failed to connect to [[object Object]:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/ajay/Desktop/NodeAuthentication/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:555:74)
    at emit (events.js:106:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/ajay/Desktop/NodeAuthentication/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:156:15)
    at emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ajay/Desktop/NodeAuthentication/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:834:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
```

I'm confused between these 2 lines:

```
var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
```

and

```
mongoose.connect(configDB); // connect to our database
```

Should I use

```
mongoose.connect(configDB.url); ??
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: And what is exactly configDB? mongoose.connect() should receive an url like:  "mongodb://172.20.10.2/database"

Comment: You forgot to show the important part - database.js

Comment: Oh okay, I'll edit the question and will add database.js

Comment: I've added `database.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in **config/database.js**. You don't specify database name and colon must be between `localhost` and `27017`:

```
module.exports = {
    'url' : 'mongodb://localhost:27017/my-test-db' // looks like mongodb://<user>:<pass>@mongo.onmodulus.net:27017/Mikha4ot
};
```

In connect method you could put Object or String, so you should use it as propose in question:

```
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);
```